# AJAX put element to the top of the list

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a list which is generated with ajax and I want everytime elements come they go to the top of the list:

My code is:

```
         $(document).ready(function() {
      var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:3000');
      var out = "";
      socket.on('populate', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    if(obj['Ping'] == "FALSE"){
          out += "<li class='red'><font color='red'>"+obj.Vardas+" is down..."+obj.Data+"</font></li>";
      }
    else{
          out += "<li class='green'><font color='green'>"+obj.Vardas+" is up......."+obj.Data+"</font></li>";   
      }
        });
    $("#database > li:first-child").before(out);//.load(blinkColorRed());
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="float:right; overflow-y:scroll; height: 400px; width: 30%">
    <ul id ='database'></ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Data comes, scroolbox gets generated, but no list elements. If I remove "> li:first-child" list works, but the newest element goes to the bottom as with simple html('out') before(out) doesn not work. Any ideas where I made a mistake?

Comment: Could you show your markup? Is "database" the id of your list? If not, try `$("#database li:first-child")`.

Comment: @bfavaretto The markup is right there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work with `> li:first-child` because the `ul` is initially empty so there are no elements to match the `#database > li:first-child` selector, so you are trying to put the elements before nothing. You could use [`.prepend()`](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

```
$("#database").prepend(out);
```

Comment: Kinda like I said. :) Good point re: initially empty list though, I actually missed that.

Comment: I puts elements to the end not to the top... Maybe prependTo() ??

Comment: prependTo also does not work, same list... Maybe the problem is because data gets generated async. so then there is more rows they just falls down not to the top?

Comment: @sauletasmiestas What do you mean? Are the second set of elements placed under the first set of elements?

Comment: Yes, newest elements goes to bottom of the list. I need them to go to the top

Comment: @sauletasmiestas I don't know why its not working but try `$(out).prependTo("#database");`

Comment: I did it both ways... Same response, newest element goes to bottom... I have no ideas why it does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#database').prepend(out);  // Prepend to <ul id="database">
```

[Here's a simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/CGgLV/).

Comment: Strangle it does no difference, I tryed prepend() and prependTo(). But the elements gets thrown to the bottom.

Comment: Did you look at my example?  Please update your code in your question to what it looks like now, since you've made the fix.

Comment: I found answer... Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

I did found answer. The problem was that I was amending a string, so each time data arrives it gets added to existing string and pushed to HTML list.

Now  I create short string with only one list value, which gets popped asap. After that, set string value to zero. Code looks like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var socket = io.connect('http://0.0.0.0:3000');
      var out = "";
      socket.on('populate', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, obj) {
    if(obj['Ping'] == "FALSE"){
          out = "<li class='red'><font color='red'>"+obj.Vardas+" is down..."+obj.Data+"</font></li>";
      $(out).prependTo('#database');
      out ="";
      }
    else{
          out = "<li class='green'><font color='green'>"+obj.Vardas+" is up......."+obj.Data+"</font></li>";
      $(out).prependTo('#database');
      out ="";  
      }
        });
    //$(out).prependTo('#database');//.load(blinkColorRed());
      });
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="float:right; overflow-y:scroll; height: 400px; width: 30%">
    <ul id ='database'></ul>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```